# Unable to open image received through fastapi with PIL in aws lambda environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, unicode, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, fastapi

I deployed the following source code to lambda as docker container runtime.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, File, UploadFile
from PIL import Image

app = FastAPI(docs_url=None, redoc_url=None)

@app.post("/", status_code=201)
async def main(image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    img = Image.open(image.file)

handler = Mangum(app)
```

I get the following error

```
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile object at 0x7f6c4c364b10>
```

Tested on python 3.7 and 3.9 respectively
And I tested both versions below

```
pillow==8.3.2
pillow==7.0.0
```

If I run it using uvicorn in the local environment, it works normally.

Below is the working log in my local environment

```
image.content_type: image/png
image.file: <tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile object at 0x0000017A88E4C550>
image.file.name: None
image.file.mode: w+b
image.file.tell(): 0
len(data) : 203801
data[:40]:
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x97\x86h\xa0\x00\x01\x00\x00IDA'
```

Below is the log not working on the server

```
image.content_type: image/png
image.file: <tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile object at 0x7fd3a07e1910>
image.file.name: None
image.file.mode: w+b
image.file.tell(): 0
len(data) : 368584
data[:40]:
b'\xef\xbf\xbdPNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdh\xef\xbf'
```

Comment: Maybe try printing the name, the size and the first few bytes of the file before asking PIL to open it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added question content
How can I get the correct size and the first few bytes?

Comment: I think you can do `data = image.file.read()` and then print `len(data)` and `data[:40]`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just updated my question.
Same file but different bytes.

Comment: `ef bf bd` is the `Replacement Character` in Unicode so something has gone wrong with encoding somewhere in your second, *"unhappy"* example. Maybe try adding the [tag:unicode] tag for proper help from someone cleverer than me.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? Encountering the same issue, even when converting to BytesIO. Something with the file format is wonky.

Comment: @dovedevic No idea. Folks need to follow up, share data and provide feedback. Maybe try asking a new question and actually following it through till resolved.